# Shared Web Credential failed to approve on iOS 10 real devices

Tags: ios, objective-c

recently a problem appeared in my iOS application. I'm using Shared Web Credential to get associated user credentials:

```
SecRequestSharedWebCredential(0, 0, ^(CFArrayRef lpCredential, CFErrorRef lpError) {
    // stuff
});
```

It was working fine until recently, when I discovered it stopped working on iOS 10 devices (possibly only 10.2 devices but I don't have older versions to check). Everything should be in order (entitlements, signed apple-app-site-association file on the server) as it works on iOS 9 and 8. Also it works on every version in simulator (even 10.2).

But on real devices iOS 10 it doesn't work. Completion block is called with error code

`-25293 (Authorization/Authentication failed.)`

`"www.webcredentialsurl.com" failed to approve "AppPrefix.AppID"`

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this? Did Apple change something recently? I'm using Xcode 8.2.

Comment: Did you work out how to fix this?  We are having a similar issue.

Comment: @Brett Yes, see my answer.

Comment: The file must be in json format. Check it on the validator (for example, here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) Maybe you use wrong quotes or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I finally found out what was wrong. Since iOS 9.3, Safari searches for `apple-app-site-association` file in `/.well-known` directory. If there is no such page or it doesn't find this file, it goes to root directory. However, since iOS 10 it goes to root only if page is not found! If you have redirect there, it treats it as if `apple-app-site-association` doesn't exist. So you either need to remove redirect for `/.well-known` or put your `apple-app-site-association` file there.

Official Apple documentation (they updated it recently to inform about `/.well-known` more prominently. When I was looking for a solution it was only partially mentioned in brackets...)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: Hey @user1963877, have you solved this issue? I am facing exactly the same one, though adding `apple-app-site-association` under `https://<domain>//.well-known/apple-app-site-association` did not help. I was wondering if you might have any additional insight on the topic.

Comment: @Solomiya In my case, just putting `apple-app-site-association` in `/.well-known` solved the issue.

Comment: Beware of the dot in the name of well-known dir. I wasn't having it and that cost me some good minutes :(